# 2D Radiation Pattern of Isotropic Radiator (or any antenna)

Tags: python, matplotlib, contourf, matplotlib-3d

I want to plot the 3 Dimensional Isotropic Radiation pattern and 2 Dimensional Projection of this onto XY plane or UV space. Code is below

The 2D is going wrong... but been back and forth for a few days and cant see what I am doing wrong

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
pi= np.pi
'''Plot 3D Patterns'''
theta = np.arange(-180,180,0.5, dtype=np.float64) * (pi / 180) # radians
phi = np.arange(-180,180,0.5, dtype=np.float64) * (pi / 180) # radians
theta,phi = np.meshgrid(theta,phi)

element_rad_intensity = 1 #Isotopric
element_x = element_rad_intensity * np.sin(theta) * np.cos(phi) 
element_y = element_rad_intensity * np.sin(theta) * np.sin(phi) 
element_z = element_rad_intensity * np.cos(theta) 
 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'))
ax.title.set_text('3D Isotropic Radiation Pattern')
surf = ax.plot_surface(element_x,element_y,element_z,cmap = 'gist_earth')
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)


'''Plot UV Space or 3D Projection onto 2D XY Plane'''
theta = np.arange(-180,180,0.5, dtype=np.float64) * (pi / 180) # radians
phi = np.arange(-180,180,0.5, dtype=np.float64) * (pi / 180) # radians
x =  np.sin(theta) * np.cos(phi)  #u
y =  np.sin(theta) * np.sin(phi)  #v
x,y = np.meshgrid(x,y) #uv co-ordinates

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.title.set_text('2D Isotropic Radiation Projection onto XY or UV Plane')
plt.contourf(x,y,element_x+element_y)
plt.contourf(x,y,element_x+element_y, cmap = 'gist_earth') 
cbar = plt.colorbar()
```

I have a working 3D plot

I do not have a working 2D plot, I have had many attempts but missing something

Comment: If the 3d component is not the issue, then don't include it. The minimal in [mre] means only include sufficient code/data/etc to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Also, saying it's wrong doesn't help. What is wrong, what's an example of what it should be?